# How to capitalize first letter and lowercase the rest of the string

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to capitalize the first letter of only the first word in a sentence.

This is the data in the tsx file  { this.text({ id: `downloadPriceHistory`, defaultMessage: 'Download Price History' }) }
the id shown above comes from the database where it could be send to the api in various forms.

I have tried to use this logic below:

```
export function titleCase(string) {
    string = 'hello World';
    const sentence = string.toLowerCase().split('');
      for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
          sentence[i] = sentence[i][0].toUpperCase() + sentence[i];
    }
     return sentence;

}
```

For example, for the input `"Download Price History"`, the result should be `"Download price history"`.

Comment: `return string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase()`

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript/51787897

Answer (score 37):

You only need to capitalize the first letter and concatenate that to the rest of the string converted to lowercase.

```js
function titleCase(string){
  return string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
console.log(titleCase('Download Price History'));
```

This can also be accomplished with CSS by setting `text-transform` to `lowercase` for the entire element and using the `::first-letter` pseudo element to set the `text-transform` to `uppercase`.

```css
.capitalize-first {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.capitalize-first::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p class="capitalize-first">Download Price History</p>
```

Answer (score 12):

Using CSS:

```
p {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
p::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Using JS:

```
const capitalize = (s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: just *lower case* the sliced part.

Comment: typo in the method name `toLowerCase` instead of `toLowercase`

Answer (score 10):

use ES6 [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) feature:

```
const titleCase = str => `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

try - make the rest of the string in lowercase as well.

```
export function titleCase(string) {
     return string[0].toUpperCase() + string.substr(1).toLowerCase()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just lowercase the entire string, and the uppercase just the first letter of the new string?

```
function titleCase(string) {
    let sentence = string.toLowerCase();
    let titleCaseSentence = sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sentence.substring(1, sentence.length);
    return titleCaseSentence;
}
```

(Also, you're erasing your parameter to the function with that first line)

```
    string = 'hello World';
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is you get the first element of string and put in uppercase and get the rest of string and apply lowercase function.

```
titleCase(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation along with code examples.

Answer (score 3):

If you want Regex, in one line:

```js
str.replace(/^(\w)(.+)/, (match, p1, p2) => p1.toUpperCase() + p2.toLowerCase())
```

#### Explanation

It divides the string in 2 groups, the 1st character `(\w)` and the remaining characters `(.+)`, and upper case the 1st group and lower case the second.

```js
let str = 'the quick brown FOX'

str = str.replace(/^(\w)(.+)/, (match, p1, p2) => p1.toUpperCase() + p2.toLowerCase())

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answers were provided already, but I'm just adding a different method using replace in case anyone needs it.

```
export function titleCase(string) {
string = 'hello World';
const sentence = string.toLowerCase();
let normalCaseString = sentence.replace(sentence[0], sentence[0].toUpperCase();
}
 return normalCaseString;
}
```

The way this works is we're utilizing the `replace()` string method to swap the first letter in the `sentence` variable with an uppercased version of it. The replace method takes two parameters, the first is the section you want to replace, and the second is what you want to replace it with.

Syntax: `replace(pattern, replacement)`

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), `pattern`

> Can be a string or an object with a `Symbol.replace` method — the typical example being a regular expression. Any value that doesn't have the `Symbol.replace` method will be coerced to a string.

Answer (score 0):

A short one using CSS :

```
.capitalize-first {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```